# How do I generate a visually distinct, non-random color from a single input number?

Tags: actionscript-3, colors, dynamically-generated

In Flash AS3, how would I write a function that will:

- Take in an integer (a list index, for example)
- return a visually distinct hex color based on that number (and will consistently return that same color given that same number)

The purpose is to provide a visually distinct color for each item in varying-length list of items. The most I expect to support is around 200, but I don't see the count going far above 20 or so for most.

Here's my quick and dirty:

```
    public static function GetAColor(idx:int):uint {
        var baseColors:Array = [0xff0000, 0x00ff00, 0xff0080, 0x0000ff, 0xff00ff, 0x00ffff, 0xff8000];
        return Math.round(baseColors[idx % baseColors.length] / (idx + 1) * 2);
    }
```

It does OK, but it would be nice to see a more distinct set of colors that are not so visually close to one another

Answer (score 0):

You could go with generator of random values that supports seed, so you will be able return same color. As for color you could build it - by `randomValue * 0xFFFFFF`, where randomValue between 0 and 1. And exclude values (colors) that are close.

Second option: build palette of 200 colors with step - `0xFFFFFF / 200` and shuffle palette with predefined logic, so you will have same colors.

Third option: as for really distinct colors, you could go with `big jumps` in every channel. Example: `0xFF * 0.2` - 5 steps in every channel.

Fourth option: go with HSV. It's easy to understand(watch image, rotate hue from 0 to 360, change saturation and value from 0 to 100) how to manipulate parameters to get distinct color:

```
//Very simple demo, where I'm only rotating Hue
var step:uint = 15;
var position:uint = 0;
var colors:Array = [];

for (; position < 360; position += step) {
    colors.push(HSVtoRGB(position, 100, 100));
}

//Visualisation for demo
var i:uint, len:uint = colors.length, size:uint = 40, shape:Shape, posX:uint, posY:uint;

for (i; i < len; ++i) {
    shape = new Shape();
    shape.graphics.beginFill(colors[i]);
    shape.graphics.drawRect(0, 0, size, size);
    addChild(shape);
    shape.x = posX;
    shape.y = posY;
    posX += size;
    if (posX + size >= stage.stageWidth) {
        posX = 0;
        posY += size;
    }
}

public function HSVtoRGB(h:Number, s:Number, v:Number):uint {
    var r:Number = 0;
    var g:Number = 0;
    var b:Number = 0;

    var tempS:Number = s / 100;
    var tempV:Number = v / 100;

    var hi:int = Math.floor(h / 60) % 6;
    var f:Number = h / 60 - Math.floor(h / 60);
    var p:Number = (tempV * (1 - tempS));
    var q:Number = (tempV * (1 - f * tempS));
    var t:Number = (tempV * (1 - (1 - f) * tempS));

    switch (hi) {
        case 0:
            r = tempV;
            g = t;
            b = p;
            break;
        case 1:
            r = q;
            g = tempV;
            b = p;
            break;
        case 2:
            r = p;
            g = tempV;
            b = t;
            break;
        case 3:
            r = p;
            g = q;
            b = tempV;
            break;
        case 4:
            r = t;
            g = p;
            b = tempV;
            break;
        case 5:
            r = tempV;
            g = p;
            b = q;
            break;
    }

    return (Math.round(r * 255) << 16 | Math.round(g * 255) << 8 | Math.round(b * 255));
}
```

[image]

And last one, if you want go with this task like a pro, [this wiki article](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Color_difference#CMC_l:c_.281984.29) could be helpful for you.